# CyanogenMod installer won't connect to internet

Tags: cyanogenmod, windows

As per screenshot below, I have been unable to proceed with the CyanogenMod Installer (Windows). 
This is what I get:

***Having internet troubles? Please check your network connection.***

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click image for large variant)</sup>

I've tried adding extra inbound and outbound exceptions for Cyanogen Mod Installer (`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\CMInstaller.exe`) in the Windows Firewall (accessible from Control Panel), but it didn't help.
I am not behind a proxy. And there's nothing wrong with my Internet connection : I'm accessing all other online content.

I'm using Win8x64, and trying to install CM on my Samsung S3 GT-i9300.

Has anyone encountered the same issue?

*UPDATE: I tried running the msi installer via an admin command prompt, didn't make any difference.

Comment: I've had issues with network connections on Android using CM ROMs & often for me it's the clock being to far off from what the rest of the world agrees on. While I've not used Windows mobile since the T-mobile Wing and my CM issues where on Android it's worth checking the clock as this will cause networking issues no matter the device if off set to far.

Comment: its lineage OS time cyanogen is no more

Comment: @xeonzolt many people (including myself) are using CyanogenMod but their device is not supported by Lineage)

Answer (score 2):

Because this question is in the active category, I'll give an updated answer.

CyanogenMod was discontinued on December 27th, 2016. Because of this, their webserver also went down, which would cause the issue this question asked. There is no solution, and the installer is forever broken. You can manually install the ROM or use a different custom ROM.

Answer (score 0):

Download the CMInstaller.msi
Extract the CMIntaller.msi with 7zip
Rename the setup to setup.exe
Right Click on the setup.exe -> Run as Administrator

And it's running without a problem.

I'm on Windows 8.1 x64